# Referent to which "that" refers

Tags: grammar

Please consider the following sentence:

> "Will I be satisfied with the depth of relationship that I have with each member of the team?"

Does the word "that" refer to "the depth of relationship" as a whole, or does it refer to the word "relationship" only?

i.e. is it:

> "Will I be satisfied with (the depth of relationship) that I have with each member of the team?"

or is it

> "Will I be satisfied with the depth of (relationship that I have with each member of the team)?"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U SE. Have you looked at pronouns and determiners in English?

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Wouldn't help because *that* isn't a pronoun or determiner here ;)

Comment: Sorry for the faux pas! In the grand scheme of things, they are important <*removes shades and grins sheepishly*>:P

Comment: Can you link the source of the sentence or post a name of the book? Did you write it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

"that" refers, in this case, to whatever is defined by the preceding article. In your original sentence "the" comes before "depth of relationship". Hence "that" refers to the **depth of relationship**.

It is possible to change the sentence very slightly and make it refer to the relationship only, by adding an article to "relationship":

> Will I be satisfied with the depth of **the** relationship that I have with each member of the team?

Comment: Small point, Andy: the article is not part of the antecedent. Relative clauses modify nouns or nominal, but not noun phrases. So it's modifying just "depth of relationship".

Comment: @BillJ - If I've understood you correctly, my edit fixes your point. Let me know if I've misunderstood.

Comment: @Bill J I can find quite a few comments of the form 'Typically, a relative clause modifies a noun or noun phrase...' on various sites. I think you'd better (1) specify which definition of ''noun phrase' you're using, (2) state which school of grammar you're championing, (3) give a reason why you think that others aren't equally valid here.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth This is all about basic constituent structure. The unit intermediate between a noun phrase and the noun, called a 'nominal', is the constituent that a relative clause modifies. A nominal includes modifiers, but excludes determiners. Thus in the NP "A young woman", the nominal is just "young woman".

Comment: @Bill J From the Wikipedia article on [Nominal group (functional grammar)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_group_(functional_grammar)): << In systemic functional grammar (SFG), a nominal group is a group of words which expresses an entity, for example "The nice old English police inspector who was sitting at the table is Mr Morse". Grammatically here, "The nice old English police inspector who was sitting at the table" functions as a nominal group >> Does this concur with your usage? It doesn't seem to. Note the claim that the terminology is _functional-grammar_ specific.

Comment: @BillJ I'm not arguing that this is wrong. Merely that it's an interpretation according to one approach / several approaches to grammar. And this slant needs to be specified rather than assumed as incontestable.

Comment: @Edwin AshworthIn "This is the cat that chased the rat", it's tempting to treat _the cat_ as a syntactic constituent, but there are 2 pieces of evidence against doing so. First, substituting a pronoun for the string _the cat_ is ungrammatical in that ex. _This is the cat that chased the rat_ ~ *_This is it that chased the rat._ Second, the string _cat that chased the rat_ is shown to be a constituent by the grammaticality of substituting the pro-form one. _This is the cat that chased the rat_ ~ _This is the one_. This tells us that _cat_ first combines with the relative clause, not with _the_.

Comment: @BillJ 'A nominal group' is widely regarded as synonymous to 'noun phrase' in other grammatical models [than systemic functional grammar] although the coiner of the term, Halliday, and some of his followers draw a theoretical distinction between the terms 'group' and 'phrase'. (Wikipedia, op cit) Rather than confining your assertions that SFG is the way to go here to unreferenced comments, perhaps a question on the validity of "The unit intermediate between a noun phrase and the noun, called a 'nominal', is the constituent that a relative clause modifies." would be appropriate.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth The term 'nominal' is used by Huddleston & Pullum. 'A nominal plus a determinative make a noun phrase' (CGEL p22). In "The boys who defaced the statue were expelled", "boys" (BillJ - not " _the_ boys")  is antecedent for the pronoun "who". (CGEL p1034). This is general purpose descriptive grammar, nothing else.

Comment: Ah, at last. A very creditable source. But hardly the Bible. I've seen a couple of articles which I'm surprised haven't encouraged them to review their stance on 'intransitive prepositions', for example. 'According to CGEL' is a necessary caveat in contentious areas.